# Data count in Athena is not right

Tags: hive, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a table as described in [the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeBPX.png).
Its data is coming from Firehose (maximum buffers: 128 MB or 900 seconds)

- When I try a simple count, it returns an awkward number, 296!
  though the size of scanned data is huge, 12GB, compared to 5KB for each record in this dataset
- When I try to load & process that dataset in Glue Job, it'd return the expected count: 1778072

I wonder if the cause was of the field `request_query` with type `array<string>`

Since the job is used for actual workflow, there're times I want to query just basic data like `ip`, `http_user_agent`, ...
and this schema is enough for those tasks, without a need for writing another job script and waiting for its succeeded

Hope that there're some ways to work it out

* EDIT

I'm running from Athena console. Here few sample queries:

```sql
SELECT count(case when request_api = 'collections' then 1 end)
FROM "request_events"
where event_day = '2020-03-01'
and tenant_id = 'devsite.com'

SELECT request_api, count(*)
FROM "request_events"
where event_day = '2020-03-01'
and tenant_id = 'devsite.com'
group by request_api
```

- EDIT 2

Attached file for a [sample data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ABnFSc9gpeNzXuDS6q1w_IbxfuRbHVdu) of 12 records I have tested and the result was 1 record

Comment: Can you Edit your question to show the query you are running that returns the low number? Also, are you running the query in the Athena console, or in an SQL client?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein still running on Athena console

Comment: @JiotaroTonthat, I would try manually inserting a smaller dataset (10-20 rows) in the s3 path that athena reads from and ensure that you get back the expected set of rows when running select *. If not, it's fairly possible the data inserted to not match the Table format.

What input and output formats does the table expect vs the data inserted into the s3 path?

Comment: @AnthBieb I did try a smaller set, 100 records in JSON, but no record can be queried on Athena, despite of its schema still can be identified as is with a Glue Crawler

Comment: fyi, 
Input format org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
Output format org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
Serde serialization lib org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe

Comment: Can you please include the data set, it will be difficult to resolve this issue without seeing the file data

Answer (score 0):

To get the right count from Athena you need to split your input with newlines (which is not supported by default with firehose)
try to add new lines between JSONs and check the count